# What are irreducible factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

What are Irreducible factors?
I have to solve this question:

> Find the irreducible factors of $x^4 + 5x^3 + 8x^2 + 9x + 10$ in ${\bf Z}_{11} [x]$.

I couldn't find any websites that explained this clearly and our course notes aren't that helpful.
I'm pretty confused so any help would be great.

Comment: It really looks like prime factorization, but for polynomials. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial

Comment: In brief, a polynomial $p$ is irreducible if $p=qr$ implies one of the "factors" $q,r$ is a unit (invertible ring element).  The definition applies to rings and especially to integral domains.  The notion of a prime element of a ring is slightly stronger, so prime elements are irreducible but the converse fails sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ is a root of this polynomial $f(x)$, hence $(x-1)\mid f(x)$. Check that
$$
g(x) := \frac{f(x)}{(x-1)} = x^3 +6x^2 +3x +1
$$
Also, $1$ is a root of $g(x)$, so $(x-1)\mid g(x)$. And
$$
h(x) := \frac{g(x)}{(x-1)} = x^2 +7x + 10
$$
Now can you check if this factors?

Answer (score 0):

Irreducible factors are like prime numbers, but for polynomials. You can't write them as a product of lower order polynomials.

Example : $x^2 - 1$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ as it can be written as $(x-1)(x+1)$
$x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ as it cannot be written as a product of lower order polynomials.
However, $x^2 + 1$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ as $x^2+1 \equiv x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$

You can find the definition of irreducible [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial). An excellent theorem to check irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[x]$ is the [Eisenstein's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_criterion). There are other ways to check of course.

Comment: While this is good general advice, it does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @rghthndsd: I read the question : "What are irreducible factors?" I guess it pretty much answers the question doesn't it?

Comment: My apologies! I mentally inserted "the" so the question read "What are the irreducible factors".

Comment: It's ok, it happens to everyone.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps my understanding of what irreducible factors are. How would I then apply that to the question I was given to find the irreducible factors?

Comment: @Mokee: I guess the other answer explains this well. In short, check for easy guesses like $1, -1, 0$. Use the fact you are in $\mathbb Z_{11}[x]$ to play around and simplify the equation. Look for some symmetries which could help factor... There is a big theory behind the whole and one comment wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Yes, I get it now! Thanks.

Comment: When answering the question, you should take into account what is written in the actual body of the question. Most questions can't be formulated in a concise enough way to be completely expressed in the title. In particular, Eisenstein's criterion is utterly useless for polynomials over fields...

Comment: @tomasz: I agree about Eisenstein and that is why I precised in $\mathbb Z[x]$. I did take into account the question in the body, it is actually the **only** question asked. From my point of view the polynomial he gave was more illustrative as he never asked to solve it.